# Constant prefix for url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to add a constant prefix for an url, so I did:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import Home from './home/home';
import Login from './login/login';

let componentModule = angular.module('app.components', [
  Home,
  Login
]).constant('apiv1', 'http://localhost:56202/api/')

.name;

export default componentModule;
```

Then, I write the following in the controller:

```
class LoginController {
  static $inject = ['$http'];   

  constructor($http) {
    this.$http = $http;
    this.name = 'login';
  }

  login(user) {
    console.log(user.name);
    console.log(user.password);
    this.$http.get(apiv1 + 'clients').then(function (response) {
     console.log(response.data);
    });
  }
}

export default LoginController;
```

But it gives me:

> angular.js:14324 ReferenceError: apiv1 is not defined at
>   LoginController.login

I tried to putting the entire url in the controller and it is working, but I want to manipulate a particular url prefix for my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inject `apiv1` constant in the same way you've injected `$http`. See angular [Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) documentation.

```js
class LoginController {
  static $inject = ['apiv1', '$http'];   

  constructor(apiv1, $http) {
    this.$http = $http;
    this.apiv1 = apiv1;
    this.name = 'login';
  }

  login(user) {
    console.log(user.name);
    console.log(user.password);
    this.$http.get(this.apiv1 + 'clients').then(function (response) {
     console.log(response.data);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To use a constant (or service, factory, provider, etc.) you've registered you must inject it into your controller.  i.e. add apiv1 to your controller's constructor

```
class LoginController {
  static $inject = ['$http', 'apiv1'];   

  constructor($http, apiv1) {
    this.$http = $http;
    this.apiv1 = apiv1;
    this.name = 'login';
  }

  login(user) {
    console.log(user.name);
    console.log(user.password);
    this.$http.get(this.apiv1 + 'clients').then(function (response) {
     console.log(response.data);
    });
  }
}

export default LoginController;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please consider that angular dependency resolution is *legacy*, meaning, that where it does not contribute to automatic data-binding and scope resolution - it should not be used. As you are already using ES6, it is a matter of:

```
/* your Config */
export const API_V1 = 'http://localhost:56202/api/'
/* your Controller */
import { API_V1 } from 'your-config'
/* your server call */
$http.get(`${API_V1}clients`)
```

This will save from superfluous injections, code noise and ease your path to future upgrades.